# SSIS Insert Row and Get Resulting ID Using OLE DB Command

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-insert

Having seen other questions with answers that don't totally address what I am after, I am wondering **how in SSIS to use an OLE DB Command transformation to do an Insert and immediately get the resulting primary key for each row inserted as a new column, all *within* the same Data Flow Task**. That sounds like it should be a common, built-in, fairly simple thing to ask for in SSIS, right?

So the obvious first choice for me would be to use an OLE DB Command where I do a `SELECT` and include an `OUTPUT` clause in my command:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyReleaseTable(releaseDate) 
OUTPUT ?=Inserted.id
VALUES (?)
```

Only I can't figure out how to do this in an OLE DB Command (with an output) and it not complain. I've read about using stored procedures to do this, so am I required to use a stored procedure if I want to do this?

Let's say this won't work. I could use a Script Transformation and execute direct SQL in that, right? Well if that's what I must do, then the line between using custom code and SSIS block-components gets blurred and I am tempted to throw SSIS away and just do the whole ETL in code.

Then I hear talk about using an Execute SQL task. So now I can't even do 1 data flow within 1 data flow task? Am I getting that right? I'd like to keep 1 single data flow contained within 1 data flow task and not have to break my 1 flow out between separate tasks.

If it turns out that this seemingly simple data flow objective is not built into SSIS then I will consider dumping SSIS altogether. Talend has a free ETL offering, don't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this can be done with SSIS inside DataFlow, but with some tricks. You need to create a stored procedure with input and **output** parameters and reuse it in DataFlow, as described [here](http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/24-Output-Parameter-of-Stored-Procedure-In-OLE-DB-Command-SSIS.html), fetching result value.
Drawbacks of this approach:

- You need to create a Stored Procedure
- Each row is processed with SP, which causes implicit transactions, instead of batch processing. This can slow down your package.

Solution without performance penalty - do it in two DataFlows, first doing value insert into some temp table, and the second DF - doing SQL MERGE command at OLE DB source and handling output data as you wish. All this inside transaction, handled either by MSDTC or by your own.

Comment: This is what I needed to know. Essentially, SSIS just is an ETL tool lacking in features. They do have a lot out of the box, but to not be able to do input/output in an existing block (it requires a script or to break up data flows) or heck, to not be able to do ADO.NET DB Commands in a Data flow is disappointing from a feature standpoint, especially for such a mature tool.